# chronic issue with boot into read-only

Tags: boot, fsck, read-only

[image: smarttest screenshot]

I have a bit of a problem with my non-dual 16.04 Ubuntu computer. I recently booted and tried to do some of my usual computer things which didn't really work. I figured out that I was mounted in read-only, so I rebooted and got stuck at an initramfs screen. I ran `fsck -y /dev/sda1` and `reboot` and managed to boot into a writable desktop. Unfortunately, the problem wasn't resolved by that; I sometimes have to go through this procedure up to three times per boot to get into a writable system, and sometimes a writable system will just become read-only for no reason apparent to me.

I would be pretty happy if someone could help me to work out a solution for this issue that is, in all honesty, a bit inconvenient.

Comment: Maybe your disk hardware is dying? Can you check their SMART status/health report and maybe run a self-test? Depending on the desktop environment you use, there should be a "Disks" (`gnome-disks`) application that has a menu button in the top right which contains these options.

Comment: The self-test failed, which I take is a bad sign. The last overall assessment was 'Disk is OK, one bad sector'.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add a screenshot of the SMART window including the attributes table and the test results?

Comment: I suggest that you clone from this failing drive to a new drive of at least the same size. You can use `ddrescue` for that purpose. Then you can do whatever recovery work you need on the cloned copy in order to save the files that you cannot afford to lose. See this link, [Repair the partition table and file system](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986). Scroll down to '
Advanced repair of a partition table, file system and/or recovery of files'

Comment: Thank you. I will try to do this in the coming days & I will report back with the issues I am sure I will encounter.